# how to use pandas and get csvfile value

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file. test.csv

```
1,1,1,1
```

I want to load this as variables.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
ch_file=pd.read_csv("test.csv")
ch1_value=ch_file.columns[0]
ch2_value=ch_file.columns[1]
ch3_value=ch_file.columns[2]
ch4_value=ch_file.columns[3]

print(ch1_value, ch2_value, ch3_value, 
 ch4_value)
```

Output is `1,1.1,1,1.1`

Why does it not print `1,1,1,1`?
Where is the `.1` coming from?

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 problems here:

- When you use `read_csv` the first line is interpreted as the column headers. You have to pass `header=None` if you have not.
- `ch_file.columns[2]` return the column name and not the value(s). Instead, use `.iloc`.

```
ch_file = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', header=None)
ch1_value=ch_file.iloc[0, 0]
ch2_value=ch_file.iloc[0, 1]
ch3_value=ch_file.iloc[0, 2]
ch4_value=ch_file.iloc[0, 3]
print(ch1_value, ch2_value, ch3_value, ch4_value)
```

Output:

```
1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you want to extract? Just the numbers?

`pandas.read_csv` rewrites the column names to be unique, so it will add `.1`, `.2`, etc. for this. In theory you could pass the `mangle_dupe_cols=False` option, but [it is not supported yet](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13262).

An alternative it to pass `header=None` and to get the values of the first row:

```
pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None).iloc[0]
```

In your case:

```
ch1_value, ch2_value, ch3_value, ch4_value = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None).iloc[0]
```

But, honestly, do you really need `pandas` for this? You could do it directly in pure python:

```
with open('test.csv') as f:
    ch1_value, ch2_value, ch3_value, ch4_value = map(int, f.readline().split(','))
```